# Resource Router :pagination not working

Tags: ee3, template-routes, resource-router

I'm using the following (https://github.com/rsanchez/resource_router):

```
$config['resource_router'] = [
    'news-and-resources' => 'www/news-and-resources',
    'usa/news-and-resources' => 'www/news-and-resources',
    'cn/news-and-resources' => 'www/news-and-resources',
    'zh/news-and-resources' => 'www/news-and-resources',
    'usa/news-and-resources/:pagination' => 'www/news-and-resources',
];
```

The last array item should match a url of -

```
http://www.example.com/usa/news-and-resources/P3
```

But it just throws a 404 error, even though I *know* it should load more entries.

What's causing this problem? I'm using Expression Engine 3.4.1

***Update:***

Using the Resource Router plugin (purely because I can’t get this working inside EE’s routing system) I’ve done this:

```
$config['resource_router'] = array(
    'news-and-resources/:pagination' => 'www/news-and-resources',
    '(usa|cn|zh)/news-and-resources/:pagination' => 'www/news-and-resources',
    'news-and-resources/(news|resource)/:pagination' => 'www/news-and-resources',
    '(usa|cn|zh)/news-and-resources/(news|resource)/:pagination' => 'www/news-and-resources',
);
```

So, based on the routes above, the following page requests work and load correct content:

```
http://www.example.co.uk/news-and-resources
http://www.example.co.uk/news-and-resources/P3
http://www.example.co.uk/news-and-resources/news
http://www.example.co.uk/news-and-resources/resource
http://www.example.co.uk/news-and-resources/news/P3
http://www.example.co.uk/news-and-resources/resource/P3

http://www.example.co.uk/usa/news-and-resources
http://www.example.co.uk/usa/news-and-resources/news
http://www.example.co.uk/usa/news-and-resources/resource
http://www.example.co.uk/usa/news-and-resources/news/P3
http://www.example.co.uk/usa/news-and-resources/resource/P3
```

You’ll notice the only difference is that there is no

`http://www.example.co.uk/usa/news-and-resources/P3`

And that’s because it’s the only one that doesn’t work, despite there being a route defined

`'(usa|cn|zh)/news-and-resources/:pagination' => 'www/news-and-resources`

Comment: EECMS 4? Already? You're fast!

Comment: Also, your first segment could be `(usa|cn|zn)`.

Comment: Haha, 3.4.1, my bad ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do the other links work as expected (like zh/news-and-resources)? Try this:

```
$config['resource_router'] = array(
    'news-and-resources' => 'www/news-and-resources',
    'usa/news-and-resources/:pagination' => 'www/news-and-resources',
    'cn/news-and-resources' => 'www/news-and-resources',
    'zh/news-and-resources' => 'www/news-and-resources',
);
```

You should only need the usa/news... once, because :pagination is an optional segment: it should match that line with or without pagination.

Update:
From Robson's comment, this is also possible:

```
$config['resource_router'] = array(
    'news-and-resources' => 'www/news-and-resources',
    '(usa|cn|zn)/news-and-resources/:pagination' => 'www/news-and-resources',
);
```

To test that resource router is matching the url, you can do something like:

```
$config['resource_router'] = array(
    'usa/news-and-resources/:pagination' => function($router, $wildcard) {
        return 'This URL matched.';
    }
);
```

Comment: Yeah the other routes work fine, I'll try your idea - 5 mins

Comment: Nope, still throws a 404, I'm totally stumped

Comment: You don't have anything set in the regular ee template router that would conflict? Just guessing.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, though interestingly if I change `'usa/news-and-resources/:pagination' => 'www/news-and-resources',` to `'usa/news-and-resources/:pagination' => 'www/index',` it *does* re-route to the index page. So, seems like there's a bug in my pagination pulling in results rather than routing

Comment: Okay, so the route matches, but the pagination is broken. I guess it's time for me to speak to Ellis Labs, unless you guys are aware of anything?